# How do you use pytesseract in a flask app

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to build a flask app that allows users to upload an image with text on it. Then I want pytesseract to extract the text and return it.

I did some research and found this article:
https://stackabuse.com/pytesseract-simple-python-optical-character-recognition/#disqus_thread

It pretty much explains what I want to do. The only thing I don't understand is where I am supposed to save the OCR Script in which the ocr_core function is defined. Because in the article he is later able to import the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file should be called `ocr_core.py` and be saved in the same directory as `app.py`.

Consider `ocr_core.py`:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

def ocr_core(filename):
    """
    This function will handle the core OCR processing of images.
    """
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))  # We'll use Pillow's Image class to open the image and pytesseract to detect the string in the image
    return text
```

Within `app.py` the line `from ocr_core import ocr_core` imports the function `ocr_core` from the module `ocr_core`.

To put it another way: `from some_module import some_func` would import the `some_func` function from the `some_module` module which is in the file `some_module.py`.

Also where the tutorial has, towards the end of `ocr_core.py`:

```
print(ocr_core('images/ocr_example_1.png'))
```

This line would technically be executed at the point where that import runs in `app.py`.  It looks like a line for testing the functionality.  Typically this should be in a block like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(ocr_core('images/ocr_example_1.png'))
```

Which means it will only be executed when you run with the python interpreter `python ocr_core.py` - NOT when that module is imported somewhere.  As per the tutorial that print line would run when you start the Flask server, which may be undesirable.

Comment: But where do I need to install tesseract? In the same directory?

Comment: That would depend on the operating system. You need to point your code at the tesseract binary, which the tutorial seems not to mention.  [see this answer for *nix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60742529/2052575).  You should probably set that directly after you `import pytesseract`.  This is also stated in the official [USAGE instructions](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/).